# How to retrieve non repeating records from table having no key?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

Im working with  a database on Oracle, I have a table which does not contain any primary, foreign or any sort of key but it has a column containing different values. The values are repeating in many records, I want a SQL query to retrieve the records but not more than once. Here is the table:

**Names**

Michael Faraday

Stephen Hawking

Michael Faraday

Robert Hook

Michael Faraday

Nikola Tesla

Nikola Tesla

Stephen Hawking

Thomas Edison

Abdus Salam

Stephen Hawking

Michael Faraday

Alan Turing

Robert Hook

Albert Einstein

Nikola Tesla

Comment: did you try SELECT DISTINCT COLUMNNAME FROM TABLENAME?

Comment: This is readily available in a google search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try SELECT DISTINCT Names FROM TABLENAME

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. Even though the output is the same, the performance may actually differ depending on data volume and what type of database you are using.

If you have large data set attempt both methods to see which one performs best.

Option # 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name
FROM   table_name
```

Option # 2

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name
```

Also, it is typical in this situation that you may want to sort the results. Usually processing the sort at the database server is more performant than doing it at the client. You should add the ORDER BY clause to get that.

Seee examples below:

Option # 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name;
```

Option # 2

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name
ORDER BY column_name;
```